# GNU SED for getting username and password for a particular SID from a file

Tags: sed

Environment:

We have ~100 databases hosted on multiple machines. All databases have **different username** and **different password** on every database.

Issue:

How can I read the username and password and TNS (Service name) from an external file one by one and connect to the each database and run the sql query and pass the output to a logfile.

What is done so far:

1. Created pass file that contains password, Service_Name, Username and delimiter ":"

```
cat pass
Loufr#123:PROD:User1
Brinj#6523:TEST:User2
```

2. Another file dblist is created with all the dbnames (that matches the service names) in step 1

```
cat dblist
PROD
TEST
DEV
QA
Quality
```

Goal:

read name of the database from dblist and find the username and password from pass file for that database.

Use dbname with username and password to connect to database in following string

```
while read TNS from dblist
sqlplus -s /nolog
connect ${Username}@${TNS}/${Password} 
spool output.log
@query.sql
exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the file `pass` this way (replace all the `:` with spaces and initialize the positional parameters with the resulting tokens):

```
while read TNS from dblist; do
    set -- $(sed -n "/:$TNS:/{s,:, ,gp}" pass)
    sqlplus -s /nolog
    connect ${1}@${2}/${3}
    spool output.log
    @query.sql
    exit
done
```